# Access Violation with FindVolumeClose()

Tags: c++, winapi

In the following function, when I hit the FindVolumeClose() line, I always get the error outlined below.  Any ideas why this happens?

*Unhandled exception at 0x11000000 in BootFixFFS.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation (parameters: 0x00000008).*

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH];

HANDLE hVol = FindFirstVolume(buffer, MAX_PATH);

if (hVol == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    std::cout << "No volumes found\n.";

    return FALSE;
}

std::string strVol = buffer;

strVol.pop_back();

HANDLE hPart = CreateFile(strVol.c_str(), 0, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hPart == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    FindVolumeClose(hVol);

    std::cout << "Couldn't create file: " << GetLastError() << "\n";

    return FALSE;
}

int numPartitions = 8;

DWORD dwDliSize = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) + numPartitions * sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX);

DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX *dli = (DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX*) new BYTE[dwDliSize];

DWORD dwSize;

ZeroMemory(&dli, sizeof(dli));

BOOL bSuccess = DeviceIoControl(hPart, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, NULL, 0, &dli, dwDliSize, &dwSize, NULL);

CloseHandle(hPart);

FindVolumeClose(hVol);

if (bSuccess == FALSE) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't get device information: " << GetLastError() << "\n";

    return FALSE;
}   

return TRUE;
```

Comment: You tell us.  What is returned by FindFirstVolume() aand what is passed to FindVolumeClose()?  Have you done any debugging at all?

Comment: FindFirstVolume returns a handle properly and I'm passing that proper handle into FindVolumeClose.  My theory was that maybe I was closing the volume when I still had a handle open elsewhere, but not that I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that ZeroMemory(&dli, sizeof(dli)) is not doing what you want it to do. It erases the address from dli, instead of zeroing the content of the byte array. Maybe ZeroMemory(dli, dwDliSize) is what you meant?

Also, the more serious error is using &dli when calling DeviceIoControl. You are basically overwriting your entire stack, and destroying the local variables.

Comment: I'm still learning C++, but isn't dli just empty at the time of calling DeviceIoControl?  I have it set to a size large enough for 8 partitions and then passing the pointer in should fill the data into DLI should it not?

Comment: You are passing not a pointer to the block of BYTE(s), but instead an address of the pointer. The pointer itself is allocated on the stack, so the DeviceIoControl will overwrite the stack variables, destroying pretty much everything. To fix that, use dli instead of &dli in the call toe DeviceIoControl.

Comment: Thanks!  That was apparently the problem.  I was apparently destroying everything right around there and breaking my IO control!  Thanks again!